# How to avoid refresh cell label in tableview ios on scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Normally in iOS, the cells in a tableview are loading on scrolling. In this time I'm setting a label text. In this case I'm setting this text dynamically. When I'm scrolling down it's working as I expected. But when It's scrolling up, it's not working as expected. Here what I tried.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"moduleCell";

    DateTableViewCell *cell = (DateTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DateTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    }
    if (self.newsSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        [cell.dateView setHidden:NO];
    }else{
        [cell.dateView setHidden:YES];
    }
    NSString *day = [self getDayLabel:date];
    if ([dateReturned isEqualToString:day]) {
        [cell.lblDate setText:@""];
        if (self.newsSegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
            [cell.dateView setHidden:YES];
        }
    }else{
        [cell.lblDate setText:day];
        dateReturned = day;
    }
}
```

How may I avoid re-draw the label text in cell on scrolling?

Comment: you found any solution for this issue ?